# How To Reuse Token From FireBase

Tags: javascript, ajax, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-notifications

I am implementing Firebase Web Notification using Firebase.

The whole process is:

There are two files: a) generate-token.js b) firebase-messaging.sw.js

1. Permission to get access token( By calling requestPermission).
2. After clicking Allow, token is generated.
3. An Ajax call is made to backend service to save the token correspond to that browser.
4. We have separate module for Notification-sender and Notification-Manager to schedule and send notification.
5. firebase-messaging.sw.js is at root. It is called when notification is called.
   There are 2 main methods for this:

   ```
   initMessaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {
   )}; ( For background handling of message)
   ```

   and

   ```
   messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {}); : This method is in generate-token.js for receiving foreground message.
   ```
6. When notification is received, an ajax call is made to api to track notification with actionId=1 and for clicking notification actionId=3.

My questions:

1. In step 1, once I make an ajax call to save the token, I have to reuse that token  in my methods of firebase-messaging.sw.js to hit track api (Track api require token and deviceId)
2. Currently, I am making device_id using userAgent, which may clash with some other machine. Is there a better way?
3. How can I reuse my token, as service-worker dont have access to local storage, DOM, cookies,etc.?

My code:

generate-token.js:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging=firebase.messaging();
var postURL=null;
var gcmId=null;
var id=getUniqueId();
var id1=id.split('.').join("");

if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    // Register service worker
    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/firebase-messaging-sw.js').then(function (reg) {
        console.log("SW registration succeeded. Scope is " + reg.scope);
        console.log("Updating service worker" +reg.update());
    }).catch(function (err) {
        console.error("SW registration failed with error " + err);
    });
}

messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {

    console.log("OnMessage called app is in foreground");

    //tracking notification with actionid=1;
    trackNotification(payload.data,1,postURL,gcmId);
});

function requestPermission(url) {

    console.log('Requesting permission...');
    postURL=url;

    var firebaseRefUrl=firebase.database().ref().child(location.host.split('.').join("")+"/" + "url");

    firebaseRefUrl.set(url);

    messaging.requestPermission()
    .then(function () {
        console.log('Notification permission granted.');
        return messaging.getToken();
    })
    .then(function(token){

        userAction(token,url);
        var firebaseRefToken=firebase.database().ref().child(location.host.split('.').join("") + "/" + id1);

        firebaseRefToken.set(token);
        gcmId=token;


    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Unable to get permission for notification.', err);
    });
}

function getUniqueId(){

    var Sys = {};
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

    return ua;
}
function userAction(token,url) {

    try{
        console.log("Calling wrapper interface to save gcm_id");
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.deviceId =getUniqueId();
        obj.token=token;
        var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj);

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhttp.open("POST", url+ "/registerGCM", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");

        xhttp.send(jsonString);
        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(xhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhttp.status == 200) {
                var jsonDeviceId=JSON.parse(xhttp.responseText);
                localStorage.setItem("deviceId",jsonDeviceId.deviceId); 
            }
        }



    }catch(error) {
        console.log('Error while calling apis.', error);
    }}
```

firebase-messaging.sw.js:

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var click=null;

var url;
var token;
var obj=new Object();



//Initialise firebase messaging
const initMessaging = firebase.messaging();

var id=getUniqueId();
var id1=id.split('.').join("");


var firebaseRefToken=firebase.database().ref().child(location.host.split('.').join("") + "/" + id1);
firebaseRefToken.on('value',function(data){

    token=data.val();
});


var firebaseRefUrl=firebase.database().ref().child(location.host.split('.').join("") +"/" + "url");

firebaseRefUrl.on('value',function(data){

    url=data.val();
});

//Background push notification handler. It fires up when the browser or web page in which push notification is activated are closed.
initMessaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function (payload) {

    //console.log("In background");
    console.log("Tracking notification when the app is in background");

    var gcmId;
    var tokenRefCheck=firebase.database().ref().child(location.host.split('.').join("") + "/" + id1);
    tokenRefCheck.on('value',function(data){

        gcmId=data.val();
    });

    trackNotification(obj.data,1,url,null);


});
//Displays incoming push notification
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {


    console.log('Push Notification Received.');


    var eventData = event.data.text();
    obj = JSON.parse(eventData); //Parse the received JSON object.

    //printing payload 
    console.log("PAyload is " + JSON.stringify(obj,2,null));

    const title = obj.data.title;

    click=obj.data.targetActionData;

    const options = {
            body: obj.data.body, 
            icon: obj.data.icon,
            click_action:obj.data.targetActionData


    };
    event.preventDefault();
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});


//Take action when a user clicks on the received notification.

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {



    console.log("Notification clicked");
    event.notification.close();
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab

    trackNotification(obj.data,3,url,null);
    event.waitUntil(

            clients.openWindow(click)

    );
});


self.addEventListener('notificationclose', function (event) {



    console.log("Notification closed");
    event.notification.close();
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent the browser from focusing the Notification's tab

    trackNotification(obj.data,2,url,null);

});


function trackNotification(data,actionId,url,gcmId) {

    try{

        var obj=new Object();
        console.log("Calling track notification api to save the data");
        if(actionId===1){
            console.log("Tracking for receving notification");

        }

        if(actionId===2){
            console.log("Tracking for closing notification");

        }


        if(actionId===3){
            console.log("Tracking for clicking notification");

        }
        obj.deviceId =getUniqueId();
        obj.campaignId=data.campaignId;
        obj.actionTime=new Date();


        if(gcmId!=null)
            obj.token=gcmId;
        else
            obj.token=token;


        obj.actionId=actionId;
        obj.scheduleId=data.scheduleId;
        var jsonString= JSON.stringify(obj,2,null);

        /*xhttp.open("POST", postURL+ "/trackNotification", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        xhttp.send(jsonString);*/

        console.log("Payload" + jsonString);
        fetch(url + "/trackNotification", {  
            method: 'post',  
            headers: {  
                "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"  
            },  
            body: jsonString
        })
        .then(function (data) {  

        })  
        .catch(function (error) {  
            console.log('Request failed', error);

        });


    }catch(error) {
        console.log('Error while calling apis.', error);
    }}



function getUniqueId(){

    var Sys = {};
    var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();

    return ua;


}
```

I am using Firebase Database, and save the token with useragent as a key, but it will sure collide with some other device.

Comment: are you requesting the token once and then using it in a long running service worker, or does your worker request a token every time the app starts?

Comment: My Token will be generated on each request to page. Note that, there is no login page, it is plain jsp.I have given try to postMessage, but it still doesnt solve my purpose.

Comment: You could MD5 the user-agent with the public IP address to create a reproduceable hash that identifies the user.

Comment: I have tried that also, but IP address will change. I want such recognizable id, which will be same whenever user logged in.

Comment: How do users log in? with username and password?

Comment: There is no login page..it is normal HTML jsp page..we don't maintain user at our end.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the data in the service worker cache.

> The Service Worker API comes with a Cache interface, that lets you
>   create stores of responses keyed by request. While this interface was
>   intended for service workers it is actually exposed on the window, and
>   can be accessed from anywhere in your scripts. The entry point is
>   caches.

https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/caching-files-with-service-worker

Comment: Hi,  I have implemented it using Indexed DB, Thanks anywaz.